# How to make SQLite query that sorts by several conditions, and works in PHP

Tags: php, sqlite, sorting

Can anyone point me how to write SQLite query with multiple sorts, that will work in PHP?

Now I have:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM Articles 
ORDER BY Published DESC, Date DESC, Time DESC
```

Other example is:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM Articles  
ORDER BY DateTimeLastEdited DESC, DateTimeCreated DESC
```

Articles is TEXT, Published is BOOL (0 or 1), and both Date and Time are TEXT (date and time entries).

What is confusing me is that when I test the query directly in SQLite client, it works. However, using it in PHP doesn't sort it as it does in SQLite client!

What would be the right syntax to sort by multiple conditions, and is there a reliable SQLite query testing tool for PHP use? (The PHP used is 5.5.3)

Comment: Because you didn't take care of the reserved keywords in PHP. Your SQLite client takes care for you.

Comment: Can you please explain? I am really new to PHP (learning it for 1 month). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use SQLite simply in PHP you can use PDO object. [Here](http://henryranch.net/software/ease-into-sqlite-3-with-php-and-pdo/) is a good tutorial about it.

To sort multiple condition:

You could use e.g. ORDER BY rating DESC, name ASC to sort by rating and then, if the ratings are equal, by name.

Comment: Since OP does not mention the version of SQLite used, [SQLite PHP native library](http://www.php.net//manual/en/book.sqlite.php) may come in handy when v1 or v2 is used. For v3, OP has to use PDO. But since OP is using PHP 5.5.3, SQLite PHP library is no longer available.

Comment: Thanks for Re! The issue is not PDO, I think. I use it, and get $result out of it. I than print table more or less in the same way as in the link, however the array I get out of the SQLite is not sorted as it should be as per original SQL query. For example- for the first query - conditions are exactly column names! - The issue is that it does not sort! Re the comment above - does PHP SQLite implementation use different SQL language than the SQLite standalone client?

Comment: Yes, they are using different SQL standards.

Answer (score 1):

I have made the stupidest error. :-(

In the end, it turned out it was not the SQL code, but missing = in PHP. SQL queries were OK, but the IF / ELSE IF I have used were missing one "=".

My code contained = instead of == for condition checking, and as I was focused on SQL query I completely missed. Here is the full code:

```
function display_all_Articles_in_a_HTML_table($sort = "ID")
{
if ($sort == "ID")
    {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Articles ORDER BY ID DESC";
    }
else if ($sort == "DateTime")
    {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Articles ORDER BY Date DESC, Time DESC";
    }
else if ($sort == "DateTimeCreated")
    {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Articles ORDER BY DateTimeCreated DESC";
    }
else if ($sort == "DateTimeLastEdited")
    {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Articles ORDER BY DateTimeLastEdited DESC, DateTimeCreated DESC";
    }
else if ($sort == "Published")
    {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Articles ORDER BY Published DESC, Date DESC, Time DESC";
    }
else
    {
    return FALSE;
    }
//
//DB fetch, returns $result
//
$result = retrieve_from_database($sql);
//
//Print sorted HTML table
//
print '<table border="1">';
foreach($result as $position_in_main_array => $inner_array_member)
    {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $inner_array_member["Date"];       
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $inner_array_member["Time"];       
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $inner_array_member["Published"];      
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $inner_array_member["Article"];        
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $inner_array_member["DateTimeCreated"];        
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $inner_array_member["DateTimeLastEdited"];     
    echo "</td>";                   
    }
echo "</table>\n";
}
```

**

There is also another way to get the same SQLite result:

SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY Column DESC) ORDER By Column DESC), ORDER BY Column DESC

I played a bit with it, trying to find query that would work, while I was thinking that PHP built-in SQLite was a bit weird.

Thanks to all who replied.